# AWS DMS completes without loading any table

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-migration

I have a database with almost 20GB in size. Both source and destination endpoints have been tested. Here's the screenshot.

[image: Task detail]

Anyone can give a clue what went wrong? I did enable CloudWatch and there's no error log.

**Update**
When I change the schema to %, it only detects one out of a few databases present in the server and replicates only that particular database. Can anyone explain this phenomenon?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the cause of the problem. Even though I entered `root` credentials, but I failed to realize that the internet facing `root` user is different from the localhost `root` user which has absolute privileges. Once I granted the necessary databases privileges to the internet facing `root` user, DMS can now detect the other databases.

To anyone who face this problem, please ensure that the user has **sufficient privileges**. CloudWatch won't tell you about this.